# It there any way to get GoogleDriveAPI supported export MIME types list in python or ruby?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

Before upload a file to GooogleDrive via GoogleDriveAPI, I want to check whether the file's mime type is supported by GoogleDriveAPI.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

We can do that by using an array which contains all mime types inputted manually, but if there are any smart ways, I want to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of export formats of Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for ruby and python.

In this case, I would like to use the method of "About: get" in Drive API. The sample scripts for ruby and python are as follows.

#### Sample script: Ruby

```rb
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.authorization = authorize
res = service.get_about(fields: '*')  # or service.get_about(fields: 'exportFormats')
export_formats = res.export_formats
puts export_formats
```

#### Sample script: Python

```py
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
res = service.about().get(fields='*').execute()  # or service.about().get(fields='exportFormats').execute()
export_formats = res['exportFormats']
print(export_formats)
```

#### Note:

- This sample scripts use Drive API v3.
- In this case, you can also use the value of `exportFormats` instead of `*` as the fields.
- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to get the values from Google Drive using Drive API. Please be careful this.
- By the way, for example, when you want to retrieve the values of `importFormats`, please modify `export_formats = res.export_formats` and `export_formats = res['exportFormats']` to `import_formats = res.import_formats` and `import_formats = res['importFormats']`, respectively.

#### Reference:

- [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)

Comment: Thanks!! I can get the list.

Comment: @yuki ueda Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.